# sending AT commands to Prolink PHS300 with Mac OS X Lion

Tags: sms, at-command, sms-gateway

Today I am trying to send out SMS with my Prolink PHS300 USB modem by sending AT Commands to it from my machine running OS X Lion.

I have adjusted the settings for my modem such as checking "Connect using a terminal window..." etc. Right now I am trying to send AT Commands to it.

In my terminal window i typed `screen /dev/tty.USBModemATPort_` but it tells me messages such as `Could not open line '/dev/tty.USBModemATPort_' for R/W: Resource is busy` and then `Sorry, could not find a PTY.`

in a desperate attempt i have even tried chmod 777 the "...ATPort_" but to no avail.

does anyone know if i may have done anything wrong here? thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found my problem - it was a stupid one. it was because the 3G connectivity app that connects to the internet was opened and hence screen said that the resource was busy.

hope this saves someone some time in future.